# How is the CSV file in table rate shipping parsed

Tags: magento2, database, development, table-rates

In Magento 2, I want to know how the CSV file that we upload to table rate shipping parsed in code. For example, is it directly opened as a text stream and searched using PHP, or is it loaded to a temporary table and filtered via SQL. Also, what is the advantage of preferring one method over the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can download sample csv in magento through admin section.

please switch to website from scope. so, you can find option to download sample csv.

in global scope this option not visible

see link - https://prnt.sc/1u1fskq

```
Country Region/State    Zip/Postal Code Weight (and above)  Shipping Price

US         *               3000                                 10
```